# ReplayKit broadcast extension crash EXC_RESOURCE RESOURCE_TYPE_MEMORY on mic on

Tags: ios, swift, ios13, ios-app-extension, replaykit

I am trying to use ReplayKit broadcast extension to record screen in iOS. I am facing an issue when the user start recording from the app with Mic off and then goes to control centre and start mic audio. Then the extension reaches its memory limit and crashes within 2-3 sec even if I comment all the code in the process sample buffer.

```
Thread 2: EXC_RESOURCE RESOURCE_TYPE_MEMORY (limit=50 MB, unused=0x0)
```

Any help in this issue will be great. Thanks

Comment: @DavidLee The problem was with the iOS version. In iOS 14 the issue was not there.